# Variable declaration with Nothing check

Tags: vb.net

Very (very) often we need to write stuff like

```
Dim Data = GetSomeData()
If Data IsNot Nothing Then
  Data.DoSomething()
Else
  ...
End If
```

Maybe I am asking in vain but I am seriously hoping that VB.Net has some construct like:

```
IfExists Data = GetSomeData() Then
  Data.DoSomething()
Else
  ...
End IfExists
```

In my dreams it does two important things:

1. No extra line for Nothing check
2. Variable A is not visible outside of the block and thus can't be used later on by mistake (just like "Using" or "With")

Is there anything similar to that that I haven't found yet?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Inspired by Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå's Answer I came up with something that would satisfy me (humbled by VB.Net's deficiencies):

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub IfExists(Of T)(This As T, DoIfNotNothing As Action(Of T), Optional DoIfNothing As Action = Nothing)
    If This IsNot Nothing Then
        DoIfNotNothing(This)
    ElseIf DoIfNothing IsNot Nothing Then
        DoIfNothing()
    End If
End Sub
```

Then I can call it like this (with the false part being optional)

```
GetSomeData().IfExists(Sub(Data) Data.DoSomething())
```

or

```
GetSomeData().IfExists(Sub(Data) Data.DoSomething(), Sub() DoSomethingElse())
```

Comment: If sound like you just need a function. Put the if in a function and call  YourNewfunction(GetSomeData())

Comment: Just out of curiosity: If *`"not visible outside of the block"`*, when/where do you plan to declare the variable `A`??? Like this maybe:? `IfExists Dim A As Object = GetSomeData() Then`

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå: Just like `Using T = New DataTable` or `For i = 0 to 9`. That's already possible now and doesn't need a Dim either. Type inference does the data type.

Comment: @the_lotus: That would take care of the scoping ... but causes several extra lines, doesn't it?

Comment: @majnu It was a **rhetorical** question. It's not supported, thus can't be done. All the examples you've listed are supported, thus can be done.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in having a full If statement. It's actually easier to debug this way. You suspect to have too many of those - time to reconsider your design - something may be wrong on that side. Which code do you have in True and False parts? It could help us understand your need better.

Comment: In `C#` you can do `if((A=GetSomeData())!=null) { ... }`. Ah, the power of `C#` (borrowed from `C`).

Comment: And in clojure you have `if-let` or you can grow your own macro for just about anything. But I'm stuck to VB for now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by others and implied by me, it can't be done. Just like to share a `3'rd` solution. This time we're going to use [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx).

1. No extra line for Nothing check
2. Variable A is not visible outside of the block and thus can't be used later on by mistake.

**Implementation**

```
Public Module Extensions

    Public Sub IfExists(Of T)(testExpr As T, trueDlg As Action(Of T), falseDlg As Action)
        If (Not testExpr Is Nothing) Then
            trueDlg.DynamicInvoke(New Object(0) {testExpr})
        Else
            falseDlg.DynamicInvoke(New Object(-1) {})
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

**Usage**

```
IfExists(GetSomeData(),
         Sub(A As Object)
             'We have something (A)
         End Sub,
         Sub()
             'We have nothing
         End Sub
    )
```

Shorter:

```
IfExists(GetSomeData(), Sub(A As Object)
                                'We have something (A)
                            End Sub, Sub()
                                         'We have nothing
                                     End Sub)
```

Or, the shortest version:

```
IfExists(GetSomeData(), Sub(A As Object) Debug.WriteLine(A.ToString()), Sub() Debug.WriteLine("Nothing"))
```

Comment: Ha!  I was trying to think of some way to do it with lambda, but it wasn't coming to me immediately.  Your solution solves all the problems, so +1 to you :)  I can't say I'd recommend using it, since it's far more confusing than a simple `If` block, but it does technically work.  Although it's probably more lines of code, total, due to the syntax for multi-line lambda expressions.

Comment: So there is a wizard around :) Let me see if I can refine that even a tad more. Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: @StevenDoggart Haha! Yeah.. I totally agree. I think it's waaay simpler doing it the "normal" way. But I *think* this is as close as it gets. And FTR, I do not recommend using it in production code.

Comment: @majnu There's always a wizard around;)

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå: Sorry, it looks like I can't post multi line code in a comment. But if I make a whole new entry I would need to answer my own question. Which I don't want since the credits will go to you if not some even greater wizard appears ;) Or is there another way?

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå: Okay I edited my post with what I came up with. Was also wondering why you use DynamicInvoke. What do you think wizard?

Comment: @majnu `TrueAction(This)` is the same as `TrueAction.Invoke(This)`.

Comment: @majnu I could have used `Invoke` instead of `DynamicInvoke`, but from seeing your code, I pictured you as an "Option Strict Off" guy. (no offence)

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå: Yeah, I do like type checking, but there are sometimes points when it can be too strict for me. But not regarding that, what do you think of what I came up with, inspired by your answer. I really like it myself! But that is maybe because I like functional languages a lot, where code often looks like that.

Comment: @majnu Yeah, I see what you mean. But, as I like to say it: *"It's better to be strict then sorry"* ;) To be honest, I have implemented many function like this. It's all about knowing the pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is nothing like that currently in VB.NET.  The closest thing you could do to approximate that behavior would be to write a function like this:

```
Public Function Assign(ByRef target As Object, value As Object) As Boolean
    target = value
    Return (target IsNot Nothing)
End Function
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
Dim A As SomeType
If Assign(A, GetSomeData()) Then
    ' ...
Else
    ' ...
End If
```

But, as you pointed out, that doesn't really solve either of your stated problems.  It's still an extra line of code, and the variable is still not scoped to only be accessible within the block where it was properly assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The first point is not possible. There is no way to declare a variable and check it in a single statement.

The second point is sort of possible. Creating your own block scope is not supported by VB.NET, but you can achieve it by abusing other blocks. Insert your code within a single-use `Loop While` block:

```
Do
    Dim A = GetSomeData()
    If A IsNot Nothing Then
        ...
    Else
        ...
    End If
Loop While False
```

The `Do` block will be entered, with `A` declared local to that block, then the block will immediately exit at `While False`, and `A` will no longer be accessible.

A probably better way to simplify this is by restructuring the code into more, smaller methods so that the `If ... Else` is the entire method and there is no possibility of accidentally accessing an outdated variable later. When you do this, you can also exit early from the method in the simpler case instead of keeping both `If` and `Else` branches:

```
    Dim A = GetSomeData()
    If A Is Nothing Then
        ...
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: For scoping I often do what you suggest at the top. I use `With Nothing` blocks though. They don't suggest the next code reader that anything else might be going on here.

Comment: Probably you are right that it can't be done. But I'll leave the question open for a little. Maybe some wizard drops by with an awesome solution. Just dreaming I guess :)